# Arquillian - strange warning, about something not being invoked

Tags: module, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I am struggling to get Arquillian to run on an esoteric project that I am working on. Whilst I am still working on this failure to run, which has to do with sharing and referencing wildfly modules, I am also getting the following warning out of Arquillian.

For peace of mind and in the hope of identifying whether the warning is a contributing factor to the issues I am having, I would like to understand its cause and how to stop it.

I get the following on deploy...

```
May 09, 2017 10:44:06 AM org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl resolveArguments
WARNING: Argument 2 for ArquillianServiceDeployer.doServiceDeploy is null. It won't be invoked.
```

and the following on un-deploy...

```
May 09, 2017 10:44:18 AM org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl resolveArguments
WARNING: Argument 2 for ArquillianServiceDeployer.undeploy is null. It won't be invoked.
```

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274013

Comment: Thank you, using google-fu I found that link before posting here, because that link does not specify a cause, it identifies a mystery; and I quote... "Too many days past! I have fixed the problem but I can't remind how!"

Comment: The important thing there is "this warning is confusing and it was introduced for debugging purposes. We will refine it and only show when you run your tests with -Darquillian.debug=true property." - this is Arquillian's debug message that likely doesn't matter to anyone other than the Arquilian developers.

Comment: 2021 and the mystery remains.. Facing the same situation. Running the test on Eclipse IDE it works, but `mvn clean install` keeps stuck.